# Powershell covert tab to spaces in HTML mail

Tags: powershell, character-encoding

I created a script that converts a docx file to html file.
The html file is sent as html text via email.
To convert the doc to html I do this way.

```
function ConvertDocToHtml {

  [cmdletbinding()]

  param($DocFile,[string]$HTMLTemplate)

  # Fix Type Error
  Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

  $saveFormat = [Enum]::Parse([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat], "wdFormatFilteredHTML");
  $word = new-object -comobject word.application
  $word.Visible = $False
  $opendoc = $word.documents.open($DocFile.FullName);
  $opendoc.saveas($HTMLTemplate, $saveFormat);
  $opendoc.close();

  $word.quit();
}
```

To fix special characters in HTML text before send email I use a replace function like this

```
$Body = Get-Content $HTMLFile -Raw
$BodyHTML = ReplaceChars $Body

function ReplaceChars {

  [cmdletbinding()]

  # EncodeHTMLSpecialChars
  $Streng = $Streng.Replace("à", "&agrave;");
  $Streng = $Streng.Replace("è", "&egrave;");
  $Streng = $Streng.Replace("€", "&euro;");
  ...

  Send-MailMessage ... -Body $BodyHTML -BodyAsHtml
```

Everything works fine, but when I use the **tab** or **more than one space** in the docx file, the text of the email shows these characters

```
TotalÂ Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â € 100,00
```

I tried to convert in this way but with no success

```
$Streng = $Streng.Replace("Â", "&emsp;");
```

How could I solve this problem?
Thanks

Comment: It looks like *somewhere* the UTF-8-encoding of a no-break space (bytes `0xc2 0xa0`) is being misinterpreted; You can try to add `-Encoding Utf8` to `Get-Content` and/or `Send-MailMessage`.

Answer (score 1):

Word's save-as-HTML will replace tab characters with [no-break spaces](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a0/index.htm) (`160` / `0xa0`).

Replacing such characters can be done with `.Replace()`, but as each tab is expanded to several spaces, a regex hits the spot. Like so,

```
# Replace no-break spaces with ordinary spaces
[regex]::replace($Streng , '\xa0+', ' ')
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution but in this way I remove Â characters but lost the right format of tabulation